# WSO2 How to set ReplyFileName in VFS

Tags: xml, wso2, vfs

I use VFS transform a file from txt to xml. My txt file name is:`COS_201205071103_0000000001.txt`. And the ReplyFileName must be `COS_201205071103_0000000001.XML`. I think I need get the txt file name and change it to xml. But how to get the `txt` file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the In Sequence, you can set the file name to a property like this..

```
<property name="filename" expression="fn:concat(get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME'), '.xml')"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="show-name" expression="get-property('filename')"/>
            </log>
```

Then you can set the output file later like this.

```
<property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="get-property('filename')" scope="transport"/>
```